# How are Andros and Hyla conceived?

Tags: dune

As I am still reading *Sisterhood of Dune* my question may be answered in due time. However, how were Andros and Hyla made from Agamemnon's sperm and a slave's egg if all of his sperm was destroyed on Earth almost 100 years before they are conceived during the initial Jihad?